# Server seems up, but accepts no connections whatsoever

Tags: linux, networking

I have a problem with a Debian based Server, unfortunately housed in a remote location.
Two days ago, it was suddenly down and completely unreachable. After having someone reboot it, it worked for about a day, then seemed to be down again.

This time, however, it was different:

-The server reacts to pings

-It is scannable, and all the relevant ports are open
But:

-Open shells were immediately blocked, and no warning had been shown

-It's not possible to open any connection - the TCP/IP handshake seems to have some problems:

[SSH handshake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1vVj.png)

As this is a private server of a small community, we don't have the resources to pay a technician to fix the problem for us, so any hints how to fix the problem after the next reboot would be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like some process on the machine is going out of control and consuming so many resources the rest of the system can't function. (RAM, CPU, disk IO). (Or, as others point out, it could be a firewall issue. Or something on the network in between.)

But right now, you have no visibility into what's going on. You need that.

You should:

- set up remote logging with syslog
- set up a remote [monitoring](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/monitoring) system of some sort

And, since the problem seems to be happening quickly and currently, you can take an ad hoc approach as well: run `top` remotely via ssh and leave that open. Watch what happens when the system dies next. But ultimately, you'll benefit from remote logging anyway, so might as well set that up.

Comment: mattdm, it really was clogged up ram, and with your tips i was able to diagnose the faulty script fast enough - a runsv script in combination with an updated, but incompatible software package lead to the spawning of thousands of tasks...

However I'm still amazed by the effect that this had :-/

Comment: It's possible to configure a Linux system to be more resistant to that kind of resource exhaustion, but it decreases flexibility (and possibly overall performance), so distributions are generally not configured that way out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

If you have out-of-band access to the server such as serial console or KVM; you should log in and diagnose the server from there.

To me it sounds like either the whole system is **hanged** (but ping is handled at a low level by the kernel, which is why it still works) or you have a **firewall** that is blocking you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a problem with the firewall.
1. client-> Server syn
2. server-> client syn,ack
3. client-> ack

From the screen shot it appears that your ACK in step 3 are not being acknowledged by the server. I think you firewall doesn't allow related connections.  You would need a similar rule in your iptables.

-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 0):

mattdm, it really was clogged up ram, and with your tips i was able to diagnose the faulty script fast enough - a runsv script in combination with an updated, but incompatible software package lead to the spawning of thousands of tasks...

However I'm still amazed by the effect that this had :-/

Comment: Please post comments as comments, not answers. This is not a discussion forum.